# Setting viewstate on postback

Tags: asp.net, postback, viewstate

I am trying to set a ViewState-variable when a button is pressed, but it only works the second time I click the button. Here is the code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        lblInfo.InnerText = String.Format("Hello {0} at {1}!", YourName, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    }
}

private string YourName
{
    get { return (string)ViewState["YourName"]; }
    set { ViewState["YourName"] = value; }
}


protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    YourName = txtName.Text;

}
```

Is there something I am missing? Here is the form-part of the design-file, very basic just as a *POC*:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
Enter your name: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="OK" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
<hr />
<label id="lblInfo" runat="server"></label>
</div>
</form>
```

**PS:** The sample is very simplified, "use `txtName.Text` instead of ViewState" is not the correct answer, I need the info to be in ViewState.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Page_Load` fires before `btnSubmit_Click`.

If you want to do something after your postback events have fired use `Page_PreRender`.

```
//this will work because YourName has now been set by the click event
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
        lblInfo.InnerText = String.Format("Hello {0} at {1}!", YourName, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
}
```

The basic order goes:

- Page init fires (init cannot access ViewState)
- ViewState is read
- Page load fires
- Any events fire
- PreRender fires
- Page renders